# [Bug]: Cannot find module '@ngrx/effects/testing' after version updates

Tags: angular, jestjs, ngrx

I migrated the project from version 25 to 27 and the module '@ngrx/effects/testing' cannot more found. In my case the baseUrl in the project set to './src'.In other projects with baseUrl '.' and with the same jest, angular, ngrx the tests run without problems. Maybe some additional configuration for jest required?

This the message I get:

`Cannot find module '@ngrx/store/testing' from 'src/app/app.component.spec.ts'.`

some dependencies from package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "13.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "13.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "13.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "13.0.2",
    "@angular/localize": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "13.0.2",
        ...
    "@ngrx/effects": "13.0.1",
    "@ngrx/entity": "13.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "13.0.1",
}
"devDependencies": {
 "@types/jest": "27.0.3",
   "jest": "^27.4.3",
    "jest-junit": "13.0.0",
    "jest-marbles": "3.0.1",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^11.0.1",
      ...
}
```

BaseUrl is set to "./src" in the tsconfig.json.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

And here is the jest config:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/setupJest.ts"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: this bug is resolved in v13.0.2

This is a known issue and is already solved in https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/3248, which will be included in the next release of ngrx.

Until then you can install a nightly version, https://ngrx.io/guide/nightlies